# React Typescript type of history and props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I wanna use the setName in Home Component, but it says cannot find the type of history

the error at Home Component

```
//App.tsx
<Home setName={setName}>
```

Type '{ setName: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string | undefined>>; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Home': history, location, matchts(2739)

App.tsx

```
import { useState } from 'react';

setupIonicReact();

const App: React.FC = () => {

  const [name, setName] = useState<string>();

  return (
    <IonApp>
      <IonReactRouter>
        <IonRouterOutlet>
          <Route
            path='/home'
            render={() => <Home setName={setName}/>} />
        </IonRouterOutlet>
      </IonReactRouter>
    </IonApp>
  )
};

export default App;
```

Home.tsx

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';

interface HomeProps extends RouteComponentProps{
  setName: any;
}

const Home: React.FC<HomeProps> = ({ history }, prop ) => {
//somthing
}
export default Home
```

The extends is not working.
How can I get the type of history?

Comment: One problem I can see is that your component `Home` has the same type name as the `interface Home`. The latter should probably be named `HomeProps`.

Comment: The render callback is typed as following (at least- in react-router v5):

render?: (props: RouteComponentProps<any>) => React.ReactNode;

So you can use them to fill the missing ones of Home component.

Answer (score 0):

In `Home.tsx`

1. Use the `useHistory` hook

```
interface HomeProps {
  setName: any;
}
const Home: React.FC<HomeProps> = (props) => {
  const history = useHistory()
}
```

Or

2. Use the `withRouter` HOC

```
interface HomeProps extends RouteComponentProps{
 setName: any;
}

const Home: React.FC<HomeProps> = ({ history, setName } ) => {
//somthing
}
export default withRouter(Home);
```